# Двойная виртуализация

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-10, виртуализация

wmvare esxi 5.0 не поддерживает в качестве гостевой ос windows 10.

Заработает следующая схема: на wmvare esxi 5.0 подымаем debian 6.0, на который ставим virtualbox 5.0.14 и уже на нем настраиваем гостевую ос windows 10?

Comment: Вы думаете, мы это пробовали? о_О Вот попробуйте и расскажите нам о результатах.

Answer (score 2):

Можно установить Windows 10 выбрав в качестве гостевой ОС Windows 8.
Вам надо обновить ESXi до, как минимум, ESXi 5.0 Patch 04 (build 821926), в котором добавлена поддержка 8 и 2012 Сервер (http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2006859).
VMWare Tools установить вручную.

Comment: Такая мысль была, но в силу бюрократии, она не применима. Отсюда ищем решение другими способами.

Comment: А в чем выражается бюрократия? Не позволяет патчить ПО?

Comment: Админы заказчика опасаются, что после обновления может что-то перестать работать, а тех поддержки на wmvare у них нет

Comment: Обновлялся более года назад, без проблем все прошло на серверах  Dell PowerEdge R515. Гости разные - от CentOS и Винды до vWLC. Так что самый простой путь - наставить админов на путь истинный и обновится.